# Is there a general preference for tag plurality? (Also involves synonyms)

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I just suggested a synonym for [domain](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domain) and [domains](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domains) with the singular as master.
 I'd personally lean toward the *plural* being the master, but it's only got one entry versus the other being well-populated. (Does that matter?) I checked the [all synonyms](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms) page, but I can't see any pattern there, either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general we favor the plural version -- this is consistent (or at least it's supposed to be) across all sites.

Unless there's some clear, compelling reason not to, that is...

Ironically (perhaps?) in this case I felt the tag should just be [domains](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/domains) and we don't need the synonym, since tag completion *should* fix the rest...